# What would've happened during the 75th Hunger games if one district was missing a victor for a gender?

Tags: the-hunger-games

I was re-watching the series and I was wondering, what if, for example, District 9 had 2 male victors but no female ones? What would have happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, they would have done something else... Quarter quell means that there are special rules but those are nowhere (publicly)specified until shortly before they begin. That's why they were all surprised when it was announced.

First Quarter Quell people had an election on who was going to die.

Second Quarter Quell four were chosen.

The only reason they came up with these rules was to kill of Katniss seeing her defiance in the previous games.

If there were a district with a gender missing they would simply find other rules seeing they can simple make the rules. And that's why this question can't be solidly answered seeing they can do whatever they have wanted seeing they had near absolute authority as the rule makers (as shown in the 74th game changing the rules three times... first to allowing two survivors, then only one again and then two again).

And in a deleted scene of Catching Fire it was shown that the Hunger Games rules were planned out, but that Heavensbee burned the one for #75 to replace them with new rules... so if the twist wasn't possible they would probably have gone with the original (whatever that might have been)

Comment: "they had near absolute authority as the rule makers"
This shows authority, yes, but not power. They changed the rules the first time to pander to the public, the second time to avoid looking weak, and the third time because of the outcry. In all three times, they were basing their decision on public sentiment, showing that they are concerned about holding onto power.